# Delay loading controller until resolved response from server without ui-router (Angular)

Tags: angularjs

There is a controller for each chart being displayed in application.

In a previous version, each controller made a separate server request to get data. But I want to combine these into a single request and share it among controllers.

So I've tried moving the request into a `.run()` block and then attaching response to `$rootScope` so all controllers can access it.

```
.run(['$rootScope', 'factoryName', function($rootScope, factoryName) {
    factoryName.getAll().success(function(data) {
        $rootScope.data = data;
    });
}])
```

The problem is its an asynchronous request, so controllers try to load the data from `$rootScope` before the response comes back from server, and crashes the app.

Normally I would use `resolve` from `$stateProvider` to get the response before state load, but the application just uses angular to make the front-end dynamic, and does not have multiple states, so I would like to avoid `ui.router`.

Is there a way to delay loading controllers until the response comes back?

Comment: Did you try using a promise?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the promise from the factory, and then **chain** from the promise to delay the functions that use the data.

```
.run(['$rootScope', 'factoryName', function($rootScope, factoryName) {
     //Store promise
     $rootScope.dataPromise = factoryName.getAll();
}])
```

In the controllers use the promise:

```
$rootScope.dataPromise.then(function onFulfilled(result) {
    var data = result.data;
    //Use data here
});
```

By using the `.then` method to queue a function with the `$q` service, the service will delay invoking the function, pending the arrival of the data.